# File Upload in WordPress Template

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, wordpress-theming

Have posted this over at wp.stackex also:

Hi I am trying to upload a file that is contained within a form I have on a page template in WordPress.

I cannot seem to upload the file to my specified directory, whether there is a special way of doing this or my file path information is not correct.

Here is my code: ( this is currently insecure for simple testing purposes, so please ignore.)

```
$target_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/event-submissions/';
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['event-image']['name']); 

if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['event-image']['tmp_name'], $target_path) ) {

    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['event-image']['name']). " has been uploaded";

} else{

    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    exit;

}
```

$target_path displays /homepages/4/d335638566/htdocs/dev/assets/themes/momentmag/event-submissions/FILENAME.FILE_EXT

So obviously I get the message "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"

If anyone can shed any light on this - great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me. It looks like there is something you've overlooked that would help, but sadly you have no idea what it is. A rule of coding that I have is that, **If something that you know should work, doesn't, it means that you've overlooked something - yet you've no idea what it is.**

All I can say is that you can copy the file uploading code that the [P2 Reloaded](http://p2reloaded.com) theme uses. It's more superior to yours, and it makes uploaded files actually attach themselves onto a blog post.